# generating reports in jpa

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I'm learning JPA and was wondering how can we generate reports using the query below.

```
Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT t.firstName, t.lastName, t.salary FROM Teacher t");

    List results = query.getResultList();
    Object[] objects = results.toArray(new Object[results.size()]);
    for (Object object : objects) {
        System.out.println(object);// here I want to print firstName, lastName
    }
```

I understand that the `getResultList()` method returns list of array of objects. But I want to print the `firstName`, `lastName` and `salary` here. How can I do that? I cannot simply cast `Object` into `String`.

Comment: You have a Teacher entity, right?

Comment: Why couldn't you cast Object to String, if you know the object is a String? That's what a cast is all about. Why are you turning your List<Object[]> into an Object[][] instead of simply iterating over the list?

Comment: @JBNizet, I didn't retrieve the list using List<Object[]> that was my mistake. Thank you for response sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
    Object[] objArr = list.get(index); //this will return a row of your result into objArr
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        //here, you are now iterating through the columns in each row. Since your select query has 3 columns j <3 in the for loop
        System.out.println(objArr[j].toString());
    }
}
```